# SQL create table query won't accept foreign key

Tags: python, sql, pgadmin

I have written some SQL code in python format using PGAdmin 4 servers to create some basic tables for my database (soccer games, keeping track of scores and such) and for some reason the definition of the table match (the third table) throws and exception that states "there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "stadium"" although Stadiumid is a key is stadium.

What could be the problem?

```
    conn = Connector.DBConnector()
    query = sql.SQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.team
    (Teamid integer NOT NULL CHECK(Teamid > 0),
    PRIMARY KEY (Teamid))")
    rows_effected, _ = conn.execute(query)

    query = sql.SQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.stadium
    ( Stadiumid integer NOT NULL CHECK(Stadiumid > 0),
      Capacity integer NOT NULL CHECK(Capacity > 0),
      Belong_to integer NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (Stadiumid),
      UNIQUE (Belong_to))")
    rows_effected, _ = conn.execute(query)

    query = sql.SQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.match(
    Matchid integer NOT NULL CHECK(Matchid > 0),
    Competition text NOT NULL CHECK(Competition = 'International' OR Competition ='Domestic'),
    Homeid integer NOT NULL CHECK(Homeid > 0),
    Awayid integer NOT NULL CHECK(Awayid > 0),
    Crowd integer, Stadiumid integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (Matchid),
    CHECK(Homeid <> Awayid), 
    FOREIGN KEY (Homeid) REFERENCES team(Teamid),
    FOREIGN KEY (Awayid) REFERENCES team(Teamid), 
    FOREIGN KEY (Stadiumid) REFERENCES stadium(Stadiumid) ON DELETE CASCADE)")
    rows_effected, _ = conn.execute(query)

    query = sql.SQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.player (
    Playerid integer NOT NULL CHECK(Playerid > 0),
    Teamid integer NOT NULL CHECK(Teamid > 0),
    Age integer NOT NULL CHECK(Age > 0),
    Height integer NOT NULL CHECK(Height > 0),
    Preferred_foot text NOT NULL CHECK(Preferred_foot = 'Left' OR Preferred_foot = 'Right'),
    PRIMARY KEY (Playerid),
    FOREIGN KEY (Teamid) REFERENCES team(Teamid))")
    rows_effected, _ = conn.execute(query)

    query = sql.SQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.score( 
    Matchid integer NOT NULL CHECK(Matchid > 0),
    Playerid integer NOT NULL CHECK(Playerid > 0),
    Amount integer NOT NULL CHECK(Amount > 0),
    PRIMARY KEY (Matchid, Playerid),
    FOREIGN KEY (Matchid) REFERENCES match(Matchid) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (Playerid) REFERENCES player(Playerid) ON DELETE CASCADE)")
    rows_effected, _ = conn.execute(query)
```

Comment: You are missing a `)` at the very end after `CASCADE`. Apart from that it all works well. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4LeW2DKHFU9nqDPsbMjGct/0

Comment: fixed it but it still throws the exception when it tries to create match
it doesnt even get to the score line

Comment: It doesn't according to the fiddle I created. Avoid using `IF NOT EXISTS` because the engine may not execute the create table if it already exists... and it could be an old table with wrong columns. I suggest you make sure you DROP all tables and start from a clean slate.

Comment: that might be just it, ill check it out